# Compiling Android example for Tensorflow

Tags: android, android-ndk, tensorflow, deep-learning, bazel

In the official example for using Tensorflow models in an Android app : [github link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) they mention changing entries in `<workspace_root>/WORKSPACE`.

I don't know which file this is and where to find it. I am used to developing Android app on Android studio and have never worked with `workspace` in Android before.

Please tell me which exact file they mean when they say :

> The Android entries in `<workspace_root>/WORKSPACE` must be uncommented
>   with the paths filled in appropriately depending on where you
>   installed the NDK and SDK.

and where to find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WORSPACE is a file for Bazel. It is a text file in the home of the [TensorFlow source repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/WORKSPACE). That file does contain a section at the top, currently:

```
# Uncomment and update the paths in these entries to build the Android demo.
#android_sdk_repository(
#    name = "androidsdk",
#    api_level = 23,
#    build_tools_version = "23.0.1",
#    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
#    path = "<PATH_TO_SDK>",
#)
#
#android_ndk_repository(
#    name="androidndk",
#    path="<PATH_TO_NDK>",
#    api_level=21)
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your comment here. Your original question is how to compile, which boiled down to find the WORKSPACE file. There it is, and the documentation exert you pasted in your question hints at how to use it.